# Set parameters for multiple read.table()s for identical files as a variable

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I am often in the situation where I have multiple files that have identical structure but different content, which ends up in the situation where I have ugly and repetitive `read.table()` lines. For example:

```
df1 <- read.table("file1.tsv", fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "", sep = "\t")
df2 <- read.table("file2.tsv", fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "", sep = "\t")
df3 <- read.table("file3.tsv", fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "", sep = "\t")
df4 <- read.table("file4.tsv", fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "", sep = "\t")
```

Is there a way to store the parameters as a variable, or somehow set a default, to avoid this repetitiveness? (Maybe not, and I've been writing too much python lately).

Naively I tried

```
read_parameters <- c(fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "", sep = "\t")
df1 <- read.table("file1.tsv", read_parameters)
```

but this gives an error `Error in !header : invalid argument type`.

Alternatively I could run a loop for each of the files, but I never have found out how to iteratively name data frames in a loop in R, and in any case I think perhaps an answer to this question would be useful to the community, as I think this is a common situation?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a wrapper-function for read table and set the default parameters as you need them

```
my.read.table <- function(temp.source, fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "", sep = "\t")
{
 return(read.table(temp.source, fill = fill, header = header, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors, quote = quote, sep = sep))
}
```

Than you can call this function simply by

```
df <- my.read.table("file1.tsv")
```

or you could use lapply to call the same function on every source-string.

```
sources.to.load <- c("file1.tsv", "file2.tsv", "file3.tsv")
df_list <- lapply(sources.to.load, read.table, fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "", sep = "\t")
```

Edit:
If you want to keep the parameter vector method as well, you could add it to your wrapper function.

```
my.read.table2 <- function(temp.source, fill = T, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F, quote = "", sep = "\t", parameterstring)
{
 if(exists("parameterstring"))
 {
  fill <- as.logical(parameterstring[1])
  header <- as.logical(parameterstring[2])
  stringsAsFactors <- as.logical(parameterstring[3])
  quote <- parameterstring[4]
  sep <- parameterstring[5] # if you need this to be more "strict" about the parameternames in the supplied vector: sep <- parameterstring[which(names(parameterstring) == "sep"))]
 }
 return(read.table(temp.source, fill = fill, header = header, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors, quote = quote, sep = sep))
}
```

Than you can call this function simply by

```
df <- my.read.table2("file1.tsv") # this will call the function with the default settings
df2 <- my.read.table2("file1.tsv", parameterstring = read_parameters) # this will overwrite the default settings by the parameters stored in read_parameters
```